# How to show encrypted password in URL

Tags: php, encryption, get, getmethod, get-method

I encrypted password, and now trying to show in URL, but in URL i am always getting actual password which is real: `kimd`

I guess i am `not passing $encrypted_string in url`, please check my php script and let me know that `How can i pass $encrypted_string in URL` ?

and whenever i call my form getting everything, details like: `actual password`, `encrypted password` and `decrypted password`

For an example:

**Original** upass : `kimd`

**Encrypted** upass : `5¾VªÜly.TÀîÈ¥MÜQüÑî¤‡Løø‹y\ñU`

**Decrypted** upass : `kimd`

**legals.php:-**

```
<?php
.......................
// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $upass, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
................................
?>
```

I just want to show `encrypted password in URL` not actual password, i have two fields in legals table, namely :- `uname` and `upass`

where i am doing mistake ? please let me know ..

Comment: first mistake is you are sending password through URL, whether it is encrypted or not!!

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery Ajax or not? If yes, then I can suggest you!!

Comment: yes i will use JQuery ajax

Comment: ok.. you have to call one jquery function, on onchange event of password, which get password and send to php page for encryption using jQuery Ajax. You will get encrypted response and keep it in <input> tag as value, then fire submit event!! That's it!

Comment: Hope, You are aware of jQuery Ajax! So I didn't code here!!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla can you share code, so this will be good for me, because i am native android developer and not so familiar with php ajax webservices, but can do modifications and alteration in scripts

Comment: Please share HTML portion...

Comment: i posted above please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59247/discussion-between-shaunak-shukla-and-sun).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Its not good practice to send Password through GET parameters`. Its Should always be send through POST parameters

```
 <form method="POST" id="contact_form" action="legals.php">
```

and you can retrieve them as:

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$upass = $_POST['upass'];
```

But still if you want to encrypt in URL only use `base64_encode() or md5()` in your .php file.

Comment: i tried with md5() as well but did not get solution, can you show me where i have to make changes as per your idea ?

Comment: Can you share your HTML code of snippet ?And why are using GET parameters ? Why not POST ?

Comment: i posted my HTML script, please check above, and i have to use only GET parameters that's the requirement, i don't know why ?

Comment: cool. Accordingly, I have updated my answer. Try this in your HTML. and retrieve in ur PHP as mentioned in my answr and everthing will be perfect.:)

Comment: bro problem is still there, getting actual password, i guess i am not passing $encrypted_string in url, please check my php script and let me know that How can i pass $encrypted_string in URL

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a guru, but from the code you have posted, it appears your query "SELECT * FROM `legals` WHERE `upass` = '$upass'" is pulling the non-encrypted password from your database. Although you have echoed encrypted and decrypted strings, I don't see where you are using the encrypted string in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, assuming you can get `$ukey` and `$secret_key`!

```
<?php 
// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $ukey, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
?>

<div align="center">
       <form method="get" id="contact_form" action="legal.php">
                 <p>Enter First Name</p>
                 <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
                 <p>Enter Last Name</p>
                 <input type="text" name="lname" value="" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="kim" /> <!-- uname could be dynamic here -->
                 <input type="hidden" name="upass" value="<?php echo $encrypted_string; ?>" /><br/>
                 <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
       </form>
</div>
```

On legal.php page:

```
$uname = isset($_GET['uname'])?$_GET['uname']:'';
$upass = isset($_GET['upass'])?$_GET['upass']:'';
$con = mysqli_connect(" "," "," "," ");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `legals` WHERE `upass` = '$upass'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

   // else {echo "Username/Key Error";}
mysqli_close($con);
```